# How to create a query connecting two tables using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have the following two tables named `wc_content_definition` and `simple_web_content` and two pojos namely `WebContentDefinition` and `SimpleWebContent` corresponding to these tables. The database I use is `PostgreSQL` .Now I am trying to write a query connecting the two tables with only one field from the  `simple_web_content` table and all the fields from the `wc_content_definition` table.
The query that I use now is :

```
select wc.*,swc.content_data from wc_content_definition wc, simple_web_content swc where swc.web_content_definition_id = wc.web_content_definition_id and wc.web_content_definition_id = 491 and wc.site_id = 9 order by swc.version_number desc ;
```

I am trying to implement a hibernate query instead of this. The name of the field corresponding to the `content_data` column in the pojo would be `simpleWebContentData`. My current implementation is as follows:

```
public Object[] getDocLibContentByContentId(int contentId, int siteId) throws HibernateException
{
    Session session = getCurrentSession();
    String sql = "select wc.*,swc.content_data from wc_content_definition wc, simple_web_content swc where swc.web_content_definition_id = wc.web_content_definition_id and wc.web_content_definition_id = :contentId and wc.site_id = :siteId order by swc.version_number desc ";
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter("contentId", contentId);
    query.setParameter("siteId", siteId);
    List<Object[]> results = query.list();
    if (results != null && !results.isEmpty())
    {
        return results.get(0);
    }
return null;
}
```

I have created a new Class named `SimpleWebContentHB` which has two fields `simpleWebContentData` and `WebContentDefinition`. Is there any way that I can run a proper hibernate query and get the return type as `SimpleWebContentHB`

Comment: what you now get is an array with all the fields of wc_content_definition and simple_web_content.swc.content_data. But I suppose you want to get a WebContentDefinition object and the content_data value?

Comment: Yes , thats exactly what I am looking for, I have created a class which contain these two named SimpleWebContentHb, trying to get the return as of that type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good idea would be to create a [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms) query instead of a SQL query.
It allows you to retrieve Objects instead of simple values for all columns.

```
String hql = "select w, s.simpleWebContentData 
    from WebContentDefinition w, SimpleWebContent s 
    where ...";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("contentId", contentId);
query.setParameter("siteId", siteId);
List<Object[]> results = query.list();
if (results != null && !results.isEmpty()) {
    WebContentDefinition w = (WebContentDefinition)results[0];
    String data = (String)results[1];
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is what I was looking for, thanks, let me try this,